# What is this root "vegetable"?

Tags: vegetables, root-vegetables

I planted some beetroot from store bought seedlings in November, and they're fine.  But this chap grew up with them, and I don't remember if it came with the others, or just grew from where ever.

I just don't know what it is.  Doesn't look like a turnip to me. And the leaves looked like a kind of spinach which is why I left it so long in the ground occupying valuable real estate.

[image: guest vegetable]

And a single leaf against a dibber with 2.5 cm markings

[image: mystery vegetable]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you have here is a slightly misshapen Sugar Beet. Both Beetroot and Sugar Beets are *Beta vulgaris*, they're just different cultivars. The seeds are identical so telling them apart at planting would be impossible, and they cross-pollinate freely so it's no big surprise a sugar beet seed could have slipped into the mix.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is really a beetroot (*Beta vugaris*). Just there are many different sorts.  This seems something in direction of Swiss chard.

Probably the seeds got mixed.